# Angular - How to download Sample template file from asset directory

Tags: angular

In Angular-12, I am importing excel file into the DB. But before the upload, I want the users to be able to download and view the sample excel file that describes how the import should look like.

It is in assets/template/schoo.xlsx

I have this:

```
<h5> Download the sample format of Excel sheet.<b><a href="" download> Download Excel Template </a></b></h5>
```

How do I achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: What is blocking you? What did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<h5> Download the sample format of Excel sheet.<b><a href="assets/template/schoo.xlsx" download> Download Excel Template </a></b></h5>
```